# How do I use gdbserver on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, gdbserver

I try to remotly debug using gdb.
On the target computer (Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu Mate 15.10), I run `gdbserver :4444 main`. And on my laptop, I run `./arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb ~/workspace/piCCompileProj/Debug/main`. At the gdb prompt (on my laptop), I type:

```
target remote <target>:4444
run
```

But gdb reports this error message:

> The "remote" target does not support "run".  Try "help target" or "continue".

How I can use gdb remote? When I use gdb directly on the Raspberry Pi, it runs as expected.

Comment: Did you already get this to work because you opened another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569855/gdb-symbol-dont-load) far this point. If yes, you can answer your own question to share your experience.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution for my problem.

If I run `gdbserver :4444 main` on my PI the main program will start and is not needed for `run` comand in gdb.
To have full control on gdb I use in PI `gdbserver --multi :4444` an in may local PC I use the command:`./arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb -x /path/init`
where the content of the `/path/init` file is:

```
symbol-file /home/username/workspace/piCCompileProj/Debug/main
target extended-remote 192.168.0.100:4444
set remote exec-file /home/username/cppSandbox/main
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped me out(If any beginner is out here and searching for the solution)

**Assumptions**: *Ubuntu(17.04)*-> **Host** & *Raspberry Pi (Model-3b)* -> **Target**, My executable (.o) file-> **dowhile**

**Step 1**: Make executable file (.o) file for your target from your host machine. Please find follow command:

`arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -g dowhile.c -o dowhile`

Please download respective libraries to run this command successfully.

**Step 2**: Copy the generated executable file (dowhile.o) to the target machine like stated below:

`scp dowhile root@10.x.y.z:/xxxx/yyyy/`

(Please fill x and y details according to your target and source)

Also, check the copied executable is working fine:

`./dowhile`

**Step 3**: Run `gdbserver` on your target machine:

`gdbserver localhost:2000 dowhile`

(Keep 2000 or any number for your port, it will work anyway)

**Step 4**: Run `gdb` on your host machine:

`gdb-multiarch dowhile`

**Step 5**: Set architecture as **arm**

`(gdb) set architecture armv5te`

**Step 6**: Connect your target remotely

`(gdb) target remote 10.x.y.z:2000`

And you are done :)

Happy debugging!!!