# gdb symbol don't load

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb

I try to remotely debug a program using gdb and gdbserver.
I login on the remote PC with ssh and run `gdbserver --multi :4444`
And on my local, I use the command`./arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb -x /path/init`
where the content of the `/path/init` file is:

```
symbol-file /home/username/workspace/piCCompileProj/Debug/main
target extended-remote 192.168.0.100:4444
set remote exec-file /home/username/cppSandbox/main
```

If I try to set a breakpoint with `(gdb) b 6`, gdb prints the error:

> Cannot access memory at address 0x86c8

And if I type `file /home/username/workspace/piCCompileProj/Debug/main` and then `run`, the output is:

> Starting program: /home/username/workspace/piCCompileProj/Debug/main
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>
> 0x76fe6c00 in ?? ()
>
> from /home/username/pi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3

How can I load symbols in gdb and debug?

Comment: Just to be clear, `/home/username/workspace` in on the local PC and `/home/username/cppSandbox` is on the remote machine?

Comment: yes, cppSandbox si on a raspbbery pi compute and workspace is on local PC